# Plot multi-level headers dataframe with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have read an excel file as follows with Pandas, how could I plot it properly with Matplotlib?

BTW, when I `read_clipboard()` this format of data, it generates `ParserError: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 5. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`

[image]

After manually modified the excel file to the follow format:

```
    date  A_ratio  A_price  B_ratio  B_price
0   2007    12.00     8.90     3.04     6.35
1   2008    13.00     8.78     4.04     6.25
2   2009    14.00     9.08     5.04     6.50
3   2010    14.71     9.21     1.38     6.60
4   2011    15.71     9.22     2.38     6.66
5   2012    16.71     9.27     3.38     6.66
6   2013    16.09     9.56     1.38     6.85
7   2014    17.09     9.71     2.38     6.94
8   2015    18.09     9.31     3.38     6.65
9   2016    19.09     9.88     4.38     6.95
10  2017    20.09     9.76     5.38     6.88
```

I have ploted it by the following code, it works, but I don't want change it since my original data is pretty large:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
cols = ['A_ratio', 'A_price', 'B_ratio', 'B_price']
df[cols].plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel("")
```

Output:
[image]

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `map` with `join` for flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
cols = ['A_ratio', 'A_price', 'B_ratio', 'B_price']
df[cols].plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel("")
```

Or you can select Multiindex values by `tuple`s:

```
df = df.set_index('date')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
cols = [('A','ratio'), ('A','price'), ('B','ratio'),('B','price')]
df[cols].plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel("")
```

Comment: Sorry, it generates `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` with `df = df.set_index('date')`, I think problem comes from multiple headers. The excel file hasn't been read correctly yet by pandas.

Comment: @ahbon - Do you try `pd.read_excel(file, header=[0, 1], index_col=[0])` ?

Comment: This seems read file properly, but it generate `KeyError: "None of ['date'] are in the columns"` for `df.set_index('date')` as well.

Comment: @ahbon - If omit `df = df.set_index('date')` ? Because it should create `date` to index

Comment: Then I get `KeyError: 'date'` when I use `df.sort_values(by = 'date')`

Comment: If check `df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0, 1], index_col=[0])` it convert `date` column to index, so then use `df = df.sort_index()` instead `df.sort_values(by = 'date')`